# Ubuntu 18.04 Usb installation not booting to installation

Tags: boot, usb

I am trying to install ubuntu 18.04 on a new machine that came with endless os pre-installed. i made the bootable usb using startup disk creator and dd but still won't boot into installation, i made the usb #1 priority but after  saving the settings and rebooting since it won't boot into instalation the endless os still boots up , after i check the priorities again the endless os comes first again  | ASUS G11DF-RO008D ,AMD Quad Core RYZEN 5 1400 Desktop pc

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Brand/model?

Comment: Can you help how do i find out what type and how does that affect the installation i read some articles on the net but it is still blurry , i tried in the bios to modify the booting from external storage and to set it uefi all options were legacy only so i set them uefi and back but no succes

Comment: Please [edit] the question with brand/model. Some laptops need additional steps.

Comment: ASUS G11DF-RO008D processor AMD Quad Core RYZEN 5 1400 Desktop pc

Comment: Please click [edit] <-here or the link under the question to update it. Do not post important information only in comments.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1030858/ Make sure the USB stick is connected, hold and press F8 while you press the power button and select the entry about the USB stick preceded by "UEFI:" Should be the only one if you already disabled CSM (preferable). Optional: Disable Secure Boot (easier if you need to install, for example, Nvidia drivers).